# Ubuntu doesn't detect thai number font "TH Niramit IT๙" anymore

Tags: 20.04, fonts

"TH Niramit IT๙" is a thai font which inserted thai number instead of arabic.
http://www.scdc5.forensic.police.go.th/IT%E0%B9%99.zip

I have used this font for years. It worked well until about a week ago that ubuntu didn't detect it even I reinstall the fonts. The other fonts are working well.

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v;
fc-cache -f -v; #~/.fonts/IT: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
sudo xset fp rehash;
xset fp rehash;
```

Above doesn't work.

Below show the fonts, but it still doesn't appear in Libreoffice, Geany, etc.:

```
fc-list;
```

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Linux version 5.4.0-52-generic

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it already. I think because of the last apt upgrade, the system count TH Niramit IT๙ (thai number) and TH Niramit AS (arabic number) as same, so I delete TH Niramit AS, then everything get back to work normally again.